# How to make 2 divs side by side inside of 1 div and take up the width of the page?

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to get my 2 divs to take up all of my page; and line up next to eachother.

Here is my code.
[JsFiddle.net/Ld8XK/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8XK/1/)

```
<div id="about">
  <div id="about1">
    hi
  </div>
  <div id="about2">
    hi
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting

width: 50%;

on both #about1, #about2 but it makes them go under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the padding is included in the width. (5% x 2)

Try with :

```
width: 40%;
```

Comment: or add `box-sizing: border-box;`. I have that in all my projects.

Comment: @MightyPork Never heard about it before, great advice, thanks.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of that. Thank you for the reminder and the answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS document:

```
#about1,
#about2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying the CSS `display:inline-block` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

They go under each other because they are [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements. You can do 2 things to fix that.

Either `float` them left or right, or `display:inline`/`display:inline-block` to make them line up side by side.

Personally, I prefer to float the elements, as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qLyU/)

Answer (score 0):

Well... The 5% padding is the problem (in the fiddle), either remove the padding or adjust the width to 40%.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set your main `<div>` as a relative-positionned block:

```
#about {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then, position your inner divs as absolute-positionned blocks:

```
#about1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
#about2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The other way to do it is to use @hobenkr's trick ;-)